# Query optimization: connecting meta data to a value list table

Tags: sql, join, sqlite, query-optimization

I have a database containing a table with data and a meta data table. I want to create a View that selects certain meta data belonging to an item and list it as a column.

The basic query for the view is: `SELECT * FROM item`. The item table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                  UNIQUE
                  NOT NULL,
traceid   INTEGER REFERENCES trace (id) 
                  NOT NULL,
freq      BIGINT  NOT NULL,
value     REAL    NOT NULL
);
```

The meta data to be added follow the schema "metadata.parameter='name'"

The meta table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE metadata (
id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                  UNIQUE
                  NOT NULL,
parameter STRING  NOT NULL
                  COLLATE NOCASE,
value     STRING  NOT NULL
                  COLLATE NOCASE,
datasetid INTEGER NOT NULL
                  REFERENCES dataset (id),
traceid   INTEGER REFERENCES trace (id),
itemid    INTEGER REFERENCES item (id) 
);
```

The "name" parameter should be selected this way:

- if a record exists where parameter is "name" and itemid matches item.id, then its value should be included in the record.
- otherwise, if a record exists where parameter is "name", "itemid" is NULL, and traceid matches item.traceid, its value should be used
- otherwise, the result should be NULL, but the record from the item table should be included anyway

Currently, I use the following query to achieve this goal:

```
SELECT i.*, 
COALESCE (
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.parameter='name' THEN m.value END), 
  MAX(CASE WHEN m2.parameter='name' THEN m2.value END)
) AS itemname

FROM item i

JOIN metadata m
  ON (m.itemid = i.id AND m.parameter='name')

JOIN metadata m2 
  ON (m2.itemid IS NULL AND m2.traceid = i.traceid AND m2.parameter='name') 

GROUP BY i.id
```

This query however is somewhat inefficient, as the metadata table is used twice and contains many more records than just the "name" ones. So I am looking for a way to improve speed, especially regarding the case that some extensions are about to be implemented:

1. there is a third level "dataset" that should be included: a "parameter=name" should be used if it has the same datasetid as the item (will be looked up for the items by searching another which connects traceid and datasetid), if no "parameter=name" exists with either "itemid" matching or "traceid" matching
2. more meta data should be queried by the view following the same schema

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use one join instead of 2, like this:

```
JOIN metadata m ON (m.parameter='name' AND (m.itemId = i.id OR (m.itemId IS NULL AND m.traceid = i.traceid)))
```

Then you can remove COALESCE, using simple select:

```
SELECT i.*, m.value as itemname
```

Result should look like this:

```
SELECT i.*, m.value as itemname
FROM item i

JOIN metadata m ON (m.parameter='name' AND (m.itemId = i.id OR (m.itemId IS NULL AND m.traceid = i.traceid)))

GROUP BY i.id
```

Comment: I had already thought this way, but it doesn't work:

1. If the "name" field exists with "metadata.traceid=item.tracid" and with both "metadata.itemid=NULL" and "metadata.itemid=xxxx (any id)", the wrong meta item is selected

2. It is not easily extendable for more columns, e.g. I want an additional column appended taken from a meta field "source"

Comment: 1. Actually, with this query, it's impossible to itemId = xxxx and traceId = xxxx. Because if traceId is considered only if itemId is null. 
2. I would agree here. It's a trade-off between easy extendable code and performance.